# capture the control ID in a javascript function, by passing parameter

Tags: javascript, asp.net

HI so my JS skills are a little rusty but I'm trying to create a few functions so they work on the client side, rather than running server code, here's what I'm trying to do:

I have a drop down control, and a textbox. The textbox is depended on the value from down down and is disabled on page load.

i'm trying to call a function so if YES is selected from dropdown, the textbox will be enabled for text entry. Here's what I'm doing:

```
function DependentControlByDropDown(sender, Control, DependentControlID) {
    try {

       var senderControl = sender.selectedOptions[0].text;
       var controlEnable = (senderControl == Control);
       console.log(controlEnable);

       var control = document.getElementById(DependentControlID); this gives me NULL if i do console.log(control)
       DependentControlID.disabled = controlEnable; //controlEnable has a value of either TRUE or FALSE but it doesn't work on DependentControlID
       }
   catch (e) {
        alert("DependentControlByDropDown : " + e.message);
   }
  }
```

I'm calling this in dropdown like so:

```
onchange="DependentControlByDropDown(this,'Yes','txtbox1')"
```

So what's happening here is I get the right value 'Yes', or 'No' I tested it with console.log. The problem is with the dependednt control. If I do `console.log(DependentControlID)` it is showing me the correct control, but when I try to `disabled=false` it doesn't work. I also tried `document.getElementByID(DependentControlID).disabled=false` but that doesn't work either. Any help?!

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as a runnable snippet. It's hard to debug an issue that we can't reproduce. The best we can do is *guess*, which is never a good sign.

Comment: Absolute shot in the dark, but is this ASP.NET by any chance, or just standard HTML?

Comment: yes @TylerRoper it is asp.net

Comment: IDs specified on ASP.NET controls will not render with the given ID. If you right click your text box and do *"Inspect Element"*, you'll see that its `id` is **not** `txtbox1`. You can force it to keep the same ID by adding `ClientIdMode="static"`.

Comment: no it doesn't   @TylerRoper

Comment: Try adding it. And do `control.disabled` instead of `DependentControlID.disabled`. Let me know if that works.

Comment: I added clientIdMode="static" to dependent control and it works. post as answer @TylerRoper  u got this. Appreciate it man!

Comment: Glad to have helped! I think you should edit your question to add ASP.NET to the tags, and also include the full `<asp:Textbox>` code. Otherwise my answer doesn't make sense.

Comment: done and done, tags updated @TylerRoper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we've deduced in the comments of your question, you're using ASP.NET.

This is extremely important to note, because ASP.NET overrides assigned IDs to ensure that they are unique. For example, if you were to do...

```
<asp:Textbox runat="server" id="txtbox1"></asp:Textbox>
```

...the rendered HTML may look something like (example)...

```
<input id="ctl00$MainContent$txtbox1">
```

Because of this, `getElementById("txtbox1")` **doesn't find anything**.

---

To prevent this from happening, you can add `ClientIdMode="static"` to your textbox:

```
<asp:Textbox runat="server" ClientIdMode="static" id="txtbox1"></asp:Textbox>
```

The rendered HTML will now be the following...

```
<input id="txtbox1">
```

**NOTE:** If you have more than one of these textboxes on the page, for example if you're using it in a `GridView` or a `Repeater`, do **not** use `ClientIdMode="static"`! It will create duplicate IDs, which are *not* valid.

Comment: Thanks a lot appreciate it

Comment: @Koosh not a problem! Also, you may want to take a peek at the "note" I added at the bottom, just for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you were trying to access the textbox via it's ID as text. You need set the `disabled` attribute on it's node value, which you already have, i.e. `control`.

Additionally you were trying to set the textbox's disabled attribute to the same value as `controlEnable`. I've set it to the **OPPOSITE** of `controlEnable`

---

```js
function DependentControlByDropDown(sender, Control, DependentControlID) {
  try {
var senderControl = sender.selectedOptions[0].text;
var controlEnable = (senderControl == Control);

console.log('controlEnable',controlEnable);
console.log('DependentControlID', DependentControlID);

var control = document.getElementById(DependentControlID);
console.log('control', control);

control.disabled = !controlEnable;
  } catch (e) {
alert("DependentControlByDropDown : " + e.message);
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="txtbox1" />
<select onchange="DependentControlByDropDown(this,'Yes','txtbox1')">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="No">No</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Worth noting that OP's question included the following: `var control = document.getElementById(DependentControlID); this gives me NULL if i do console.log(control)`. If `document.getElementById(DependentControlID);` is returning `null` as OP describes, I don't see the solution you've described working. Though without a MCVE, it's impossible to know. I have a hunch that your answer will work fine and something else is amiss.

Comment: this doesn't work its still showing me that it is NULL when I do document.getElementById(DependentControlID)

Comment: Your edit doesn't really change anything. Regardless of whether you do `control...` or `document.getElementById(DependentControlID)...`, OP is saying that it is returning `null`.

Comment: why the heck is this happening. it works perfectly fine in the example provided. It's able to capture controls, value from drop down, but can't disable or enable it

Comment: not sure i quite understand, i've added more console logs to show that all values are being assigned and logged correctly... maybe i'm missing something?